# Fabric - Passing arguments to tasks via execute

Tags: python, fabric

I have the following Fabric task:

```
def ssh_keygen(user, dir):
   env.user = user
   run("ssh-keygen  %s" % dir)
```

I want to call it using "execute" but need to pass the task an argument. i.e. user and dir

```
execute(ssh_keygen('jbloggs', '/home/jbloggs'), hosts=["server1"])
```

However this does not work:

```
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection: Traceback (most recent
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
execute(ssh_keygen, 'jbloggs', '/home/jbloggs', host="server1")
```

Comment: Thanks, obvious now I see it,

Comment: I am curious, why does execute function have keyword 'host' and not
'hosts' or 'env.hosts'  ?
Since I get error on using the latter with execute() 
thank you.

Comment: @gprakhar: it should accept both `host` and `hosts` as far as I remember (though I'm not entirely sure). If it doesn't work for you; ask a new question.